# Can eshell provide TRAMP auto-completion?

Tags: tramp, eshell

If I use `find-file` with a TRAMP method to navigate to a remote file in a docker or kubernetes container I'm provided with auto-completion:

```
C-x C-f /docker:frosty_cori:/home
```

In the example above, if I press  at any point after and including '/' auto-completion helps me find docker containers running on my system.

I can access remote files using TRAMP in the same way by providing the path in eshell:

```
$ cd /docker:frosty_cori:/home
```

Unfortunately, in eshell I'm not provided with auto-completion for for neither the TRAMP method nor the containers. This would be especially useful for kubernetes pods with their long-form names.

Is there any way I can get eshell to provide TRAMP auto-completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eshell does not support it (yet). I find the idea neat, so I have written a feature request, see [bug#65356](https://debbugs.gnu.org/65356). This request contains also a patch for eshell which adds this feature, you might try it yourself.

Comment: FTR, this feature is implemented now in Emacs 30.

Comment: Thank you, Michael!